# How can I get my Windows 8 app name from properties programmatically?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, manifest, title

I need to get Windows 8 app name to a variable, but I can't find a way to do this.

I want to get Title ("*TEMEL UYGULAMA*") from Application Properties, as shown in this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/psd6w

Or if anyone knows anyway to get application name or title, I can use it. I just need to get app name or title (inside the assembly)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

From your screenshot, it seems you want the assembly title. You can get the assembly title attribute at runtime by doing something like this:

```
// Get current assembly
var thisAssembly = this.GetType().Assembly;

// Get title attribute (on .NET 4)
var titleAttribute = thisAssembly
        .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute), false)
        .Cast<AssemblyTitleAttribute>()
        .FirstOrDefault();

// Get title attribute (on .NET 4.5)
var titleAttribute = thisAssembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyTitleAttribute>();

if (titleAttribute != null)
{
    var title = titleAttribute.Title;
    // Do something with title...
}
```

But remember, this is **not** the application name, this is the assembly title.

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem in your example code: "'System.Type' does not contain a definition for 'Assembly' and no extension method 'Assembly' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Type' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Do you have a solution for this too? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm, that's wierd, I know for a fact that `System.Type` has a property called `Assembly`. Just check out the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.type.aspx). If you can't get it to work, you could try `this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly` and see if that helps you, but this property is inherited from `System.Type`, so I don't see why it should make a difference.

Comment: If you want to try the `this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly` you might need to add `using System.Reflection;` to your file. There are always other ways to get the `Assembly` you want. You could try `typeof(<type in assembly>).Assembly` or `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()`...

Answer (score 1):

I use some code like this to get the `Title` *attribute* of my *Windows Store App* assembly:

First, you need these assemblies:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;
```

...and then code like this should work (with more checks maybe):

```
// Get the assembly with Reflection:
Assembly assembly = typeof(App).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

// Get the custom attribute informations:
var titleAttribute = assembly.CustomAttributes.Where(ca => ca.AttributeType == typeof(AssemblyTitleAttribute)).FirstOrDefault();

// Now get the string value contained in the constructor:
return titleAttribute.ConstructorArguments[0].Value.ToString();
```

Hope this helps...